# sci-fi stories Youtube channel

Tags: story-identification

Looking for a sci-fi stories Youtube channel. I unfortunately neglected to bookmark it, and searching for the content was fruitless. It has a couple dozen original stories in English. I think the author narrates the stories.

I can remember parts of two stories:

- The protagonist climbs up a mountain and has mystical adventures along the way, lots of dialogue, but this is rather more about finding one's place in the world.
- The protagonist lives on a space station and has a hiring interview by enigmatic spacefarers.

Comment: Was it kind of audiobook? Was there any background image? How long were the stories?

Comment: Did you look at [your Youtube history](https://www.youtube.com/feed/history)?

Comment: Are you 100% sure the content was original? There are quite a few YouTube channels that narrate content from various other places on the internet, particularly Reddit.

Comment: Not an audiobook in the sense that the length is wrong, it was minutes per story, not hours. I have a hard time remembering the background. I want to be careful about imagining detail that was not there. ISTR still images, and the mountain was grey. Sorry, I realise that's not much helpful. I'm totally drawing a blank on the second story. – YT history: I checked and absence of evidence points to the possibility that I had consumed the videos while not logged in at my home computer, likely [at some other place](https://github.com/screeninvader/ScreenInvader).

Comment: I can't be sure about the originality because my memory is vague, we have to trust my instinct here. I know that regurgitators like http://youtube.com/c/rSlash http://youtube.com/c/SlashStart are conspicuous about the content attributable to someplace else, but thinking back I didn't even get a subtle whiff of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The channel is [Existence is Terrifying](https://www.youtube.com/c/Exurb1a/about) by exurb1a

- `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7g1pmHSWHe0`
- `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=um6cGuJ4mNE`

​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​